# Azure REST API metric Collection Data JSON Issue

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I try to collect metrics for VM using AZURE REST API for some m/c's I get metrics where data is in average and for some m/c's I get data in total please help me fix this issue , I want to get only average data for last 5mins .

I'm using the following URL

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/rg-np-eastjp-vnet-10-198-0-0-24/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-dev-eastjp-waf/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2016-09-01&$filter=%28+name.value+eq+%27Network+In%27+or++name.value+eq+%27Network+Out%27+or++name.value+eq+%27Percentage+CPU%27+or++name.value+eq+%27Disk+Read+Bytes%27+or++name.value+eq+%27Disk+Write+Bytes%27+or++name.value+eq+%27Disk+Read+Operations%2FSec%27+or++name.value+eq+%27Disk+Write+Operations%2FSec%27++%29+and+timeGrain+eq+duration%27PT5M%27+and+startTime+eq+2017-12-08T12%3A58%3A41.729+and+endTime+eq+2017-12-08T13%3A03%3A41.729+`

[image: Data output 1]
[image: Data output 2]

The following is the O/P for total:

```
{
  "value":[
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":1791478.0
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Network In",
      "name":{
        "value":"Network In",
        "localizedValue":"Network In"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"Bytes"
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":1503183.0
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Network Out",
      "name":{
        "value":"Network Out",
        "localizedValue":"Network Out"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"Bytes"
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":896.99
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Percentage CPU",
      "name":{
        "value":"Percentage CPU",
        "localizedValue":"Percentage CPU"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"Percent"
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":0.0
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Disk Read Bytes",
      "name":{
        "value":"Disk Read Bytes",
        "localizedValue":"Disk Read Bytes"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"Bytes"
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":5022690.87
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Disk Write Bytes",
      "name":{
        "value":"Disk Write Bytes",
        "localizedValue":"Disk Write Bytes"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"Bytes"
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":0.0
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Disk Read Operations/Sec",
      "name":{
        "value":"Disk Read Operations/Sec",
        "localizedValue":"Disk Read Operations/Sec"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"CountPerSecond"
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "timeStamp":"2017-12-11T08:19:00Z",
          "total":10.77
        }
      ],
      "id":"/subscriptions/{subscription_ID}/resourceGroups/MWatchLab-dev-db-mcs-473968/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/dev-db-mcs/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Disk Write Operations/Sec",
      "name":{
        "value":"Disk Write Operations/Sec",
        "localizedValue":"Disk Write Operations/Sec"
      },
      "type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
      "unit":"CountPerSecond"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please paste the data output directly in rather than using an image.

Comment: @MattFletcher i have updated my question and added the exact JSON im getting please help me to identify why some times im getting total and sometimes average? what is the difference? if i need only average what should i do?

Comment: @Tom Sun Please help with  this issue

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Azure, I'm just helping edit questions to make them better readable for those who do.